# Proxmox Virtualized Client (Network Configuration)

Tags: networking, virtualization, failover, proxmox

first some information about me. I ordered a server from ovh and purchased one failover ip to test proxmox and do some training.

The main Server is hosting proxmox(Example IP: 123.45.67.89 to figure out my problem)
Now i want to create a virtualized client(debian). This debian client should use the failover ip, which i ordered(Example IP: 222.222.222.222).

The network adapter has to be bridged, right? I can choose between these models:

- intel e1000
- virtIO (paravirtualized)
- Realtec RTL8139
- VMWare vmxnet3

Which is the right one for me? How can i check it?

After coming to the network configuration in debian, i cant figure out my problem.

- IP Adress:222.222.222.222
- netmask: 255.255.255.255 (is this right?)
- Gateway: 123.45.67.254(Because OVH is saying that i should use the .254)

After entering those information, i am getting an error, which says that this gateway is not reachable.
I hope my problem is clear.

Best regards,

Edit: I got some information about creating a virtual mac and binding it on proxmox to the debian client. Will it work after doing this with my configuration which i posted? I can try it in 2-3hours.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do to add a public IP address to the VM :

1. In your OVH manager, add a new Virtual MAC address to the (additionnal) IP you want to assign to the VM.
2. In Proxmox web GUI, got to your VM and to the "Hardware" tab.
3. Double click on the Network Device to edit it, and copy-paste the previously created Virtual MAC to the "MAC address" field. (You should be using vmbr0 as bridge and Intel E1000 as model works fine.)
4. Validate the change and restart the machine (from Proxmox, not from the VM).
5. Configure the VM based on the OVH documentation : http://help.ovh.co.uk/BridgeClient

This should get it working !
If something else isn't clear, OVH's guide for Proxmox might help you : http://help.ovh.com/Proxmox

Comment: If my answer is correct, please accept it @Newbie2015 ;-)